# running react native locally is issueing

Tags: ruby, react-native

I'm trying to use this command to run react native app locally: `npx react-native init notexpoapp3 --template react-native-template-typescript` yet I get this issue:

✖ Installing Bundler
error Your RubyGems version (3.0.3.1) has a bug that prevents `required_ruby_version` from working for Bundler. Any scripts that use `gem install bundler` will break as soon as Bundler drops support for your Ruby version. Please upgrade RubyGems to avoid future breakage and silence this warning by running `gem update --system 3.2.3`
Your Ruby version is 2.6.10, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.6

```
✖ Installing Bundler
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
Error: Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
    at createFromTemplate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:129:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:181:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:106:9)
```